# Nexus4 not sending touch-tones to other end of connection

Tags: bluetooth, nexus-4

Brand new Nexus 4 (shipped 1 week ago), unmodified software/hardware straight from the box (except for APN settings) No new apps loaded. Connected via Bluetooth to an ATT TL92429 cordless phone system. System works fine for making and receiving voice calls. However, if the number called requires touch-tone entries  (eg, voicemail), it appears that only the first keypress is transmitted. After that, the far end of the connection does not receive the tones. This problem does NOT occur if the phone is used directly (ie, not via bluetooth connection to the cordless phone). Furthermore, the same ATT cordless system when connected via Bluetooth to my (antique) Moto E815 does not suffer from this problem, so I suspect the fault lies in the Nexus4 software. I'd be grateful to receive any suggestions/guidance/patches to alleviate this problem.